# UITextView text manipulation

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uibutton, uitextview

I am working on this app where I have one UITextView on screen containing text like following:

```
      1
     121
    12321
   1234321
  123454321
 12345654321
1234567654321
```

and along with this UITextView I have 7 UIbuttons 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. I want to make individual digit in the UITextview **bold** when respective UIbutton is tapped. For example pressing UIButton 1 will make all **1** bold.

I was just wondering if there is any NSString associated method or UITextView method that allows me to parse the content of it for specific characters that can allow me to implement my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of NSString methods that will assist in parsing items in strings:

```
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:
– rangeOfString:
– rangeOfString:options:
– rangeOfString:options:range:
– rangeOfString:options:range:locale:
– enumerateLinesUsingBlock:
– enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:
```

Displaying a string with one character in bold is not easy though.  You'll probably have to use CoreText routines to get there.  Probably good for you to watch the WWDC sessions on using CoreText

Comment: The OP could use `UIWebView`. If the view is not required to be user-editable this can be used to display styled text without resorting to `CoreText` and with much less code.

Comment: Yes.  If the user can use a Web view for this, and is comfortable with it. He could also perhaps get by with Quartz text routines if he is willing to manually separate out the non-bold from the bold text and issue separate drawing commands for them, and handle the spacing himself.